# What's a good way to mount an OLED display to a glass/acrylic window?

Tags: display, mechanical-assembly

I have a graphic OLED display I'm using for a project and need to mount it in a chassis.  I was planning on using some sort of clear window in an aluminum panel.  Perhaps acrylic or glass.  I'm wondering what is the best way to mount the display to the window on the inside of the chassis.  Adhesive?  Optically clear UV cured clue?  Nothing?  What's worked well in your experience?

Comment: BTW I realize this isn't an "electronics" question per se, but I figured it was probably the best forum for it.  Feel free to suggest another location.

Comment: Post a link to the datasheet your display module.  May be, there is a mechanical drawing.  If the display module has mounting holes, I would consider using those.

Comment: http://www.buy-display.com/download/manual/ER-OLED032-1_Series_Manual.pdf

Unfortunately there aren't any mounting holes.

Answer (score 1):

Since the lcd in question is fairly flat, with no second layer so you can inlay it in a window, the two options are epoxy (or other non-clouding glue. Definitely not superglue.) or sandwiching the screen between the acrylic and a backing board, either your pcb or acrylic or wood or whatever. You can use screws through the acrylic. You can use acrylic glue to add acrylic/plastic/metal standoffs at the four corners, or you could use strips of acrylic to form a box/lip for the display to sit in. You can use an entire board behind it attached to the standoffs or lip, or use small tabs that press against the display like a picture frame does.

[image]

[image]

Frankly, considering the short length of that Flat Printed Cable, your probably going to have to mount that lcd on your pcb, so you might want to have some mounting holes on it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  What do you think the tradeoffs are between the acrylic sandwich and using an adhesive.  I'm curious how they do this in commercially avaliable products (at some point the project I'm working on will be commercialized).  What's the trade off between sandwich and glue?  If you use glue do you put glue between the display and the window or just around the display such that there's nothing between the window and the display?  From an optics perspective which window materials/glues are recommended?  How do you avoid dust etc?  Thanks!

Comment: And yes -- you're spot on -- I will 99% mount the back side of the display to my PCB so I can put mounting holes on the PCB itself.  I guess my real concern/question is the mechanical coupling between the display and the window.

Comment: @doov I've never seen a commercial, non-hobbyist product with the bare lcd and wires mounted on see through plexi. Those that have lcds are normally mounted IN or Behind opaque plexi/glass either sandwiched or with mounting holes/standoffs. The trade offs between sandwich and glue is that gluing the lcd to the glass is pretty permanent. If you screw it up, you need to start from scratch, losing both the glass/plexi and the lcd. If you go with gluing standoffs or a lip, you wont lose the lcd, but it may be hard to do it neatly.

Comment: thanks a lot for the info.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by in or behind opaque plexi/glass?  How do you see the it if the display is behind opaque material?  My phone/computer etc seem to all have the display mounted behind a layer of thin glass (as I'm proposing), but perhaps that's a misconception I have?  Thanks a lot for your help.  Upvoting you

Comment: @Doov oh, by in I mean there is a cut out for the display to fit in. By behind, I mean the plexi or glass is painted (or a mat is used, like a picture frame) to hide everything aside from the display part. Your cell phone lcd is mounted by sandwiching, with thin double sided tape behind the bezel/digitizer gluing them together, then glued with foam or similar to the frame. The digitizer part hides the edges of the lcd.